# Smooth Path joining any two points in $U=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}|1<x^2+y^2<4\}$.

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Please help me to solve the problem:

> Let $U=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}|1<x^2+y^2<4\}$. Let $p,q \in U$. Show that there is a continuous map $\gamma:[0,1] \to U$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma(1)=q$ and such that $\gamma$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$.

Now, $U$ is pathconnected because any $p,q \in U$ can be join by means of polygonal paths inside $U$. But such a path is not differentiable on $(0,1)$.

Again, the straight line joining any $p,q \in U$ may not lie inside $U$.

So How to construct a desired map? Please help.Thank you.

Comment: why wouldn't a straight line joining any $p$ and $q$ not lie inside $U$. It obviously does.....  also you don't need a complicated curve.... just a straight line and that is clearly smooth / differentiable / continuous

Comment: $U$ is annulus, so if we join to points which are diametrically opposite then the line intersects $|z|<1$.....Am I wrong..?

Comment: You can always smooth out the line segments where they connect.

Comment: Sry, but I can't understand what did u mean by "smooth out the line segment"....My problem is that , I cannot understand why this straight line always inside U....

Comment: $p$ has an angle $\theta_p$ and $q$ has an angle $\theta_q$.  Use an arc function (that traces out the arc of a circle) that takes you from $\theta_p$ to $\theta_q$.  Then adjust the (origin) distance from the default distance ($p's$ distance to $q's$ distance).  Finally you need to smooth out where these two functions connect, and that's the tough part.

(I definitely misspoke when I said "smooth out the line segments".... you are connecting an arc and a line segment, then smoothing them out....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question only asks us to show that such a map exists. So fix  apoint $a \in U$ and consider the set $E$ of all points $b \in U$ such that there is a differentiable path in $U$ from $a$ to $b$. It is enough to show that this set is open and closed. Suppose $x \in E$ and choose an open disk $D$ around $x$ contained in $U$. We claim that this disk is contained in $E$, proving that $E$ is open; a similar argument shows that $U\setminus E$ is also open in $U$. Now working within the disk we only have to shaow that any two points can be connectes inside the disk by a differentiable path, say $\gamma :[0,1] \to D$ with a specified value for the right hand derivative at 0. This is easy: there exists a path of the type $a(t-a)+(t-b)(\alpha t+\beta)$ with these properties.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $p=r_1e^{i\varphi_1}$ and $q=r_2e^{i\varphi_2}$ as complex numbers. Then the “spiral” path 
 $$\gamma\colon[0,1]\to \mathbb C,\quad t\mapsto\bigl(r_1+t(r_2-r_1)\bigr)e^{i(\varphi_1+t(\varphi_2-\varphi_1))}$$ satisfies all needs.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1:  $f(x)=(1-x)p + x\cdot q$ and $0\le x\le 1$

Hint 2: What function makes arcs for a fixed distance from the origin?

Hint 3:  It is possible to change the angle from $p$ to $q$'s angle then apply Hint 1 to get the right distance.

Hint 4:  Make Hint 3 smooth where Hint 1 and Hint 2 "connect".